# What does "private payment service providers" mean?

Tags: phrases

[Lannquist,2020, p.6](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/bab1888b-3b36-318e-8d21-153b5f0bd5e5/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B1ed7fa60-0df9-369d-85c4-5cf5cb034eea%7D) said that

> Retail CBDC can serve as a counterweight to market power of private
> payment service providers

Retail CBDC is the CBDC can be used by citizens and companies while wholesale CBDC is only used in interbank trading. "[Payment service providers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_service_provider)" is the third-party in a transaction, e.g., online-banking,...

I am wondering what does "private payment service providers" mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a new and highly domain-specific usage, not directly related to "learning English". Better suited to Stack Exchange [Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/), perhaps.

Comment: There is a mistake in that sentence. I think you can easily google this,

Comment: https://gocardless.com/guides/posts/what-is-payment-service-provider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much as your link suggests, a payment services provider is an organisation that makes it convenient for businesses to take a variety of payments. Private companies like "Square" let small merchants accept credit cards or online payments, reducing risks to the merchant, but for a fee.

Private payment service providers are private companies, not part of a national bank.  The article is about "Central Bank Digital Currency", and the possibilities of a nation setting up a digital currency, "Retail CBDC" would be an alternative way for small merchants to take online payments without using a private payment services provider like "Square".